# Data storage in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I want to store objects in jquery. The objects are 'events' each event has a date, title and some text. They need to be stored like and array (maybe thats what they will be a multi-dimensional array) so I can iterate through them with a counter.

Edit,

I like the stores var as a way to group the info but how do I add multiple items and how do I index them?

```
var dates = new Array('12th Dec', '14th Jan', '6th May');
var event_title = new Array('My Birthday', 'Going to Beach', 'Holiday');
var event_text = new Array('One Year Older', 'Remember the suntan lotion', 'on the plane to spain');

I need to return by index alert(dates[2], event_title[2], event_text[2]);
```

Comment: not tried anything was looking at the simplest way to create data structures.

Comment: an array? an object? these can both be looped through

Comment: suppose I could have dates[], titles[], infotxt[] as 3 arrays and just access them by index. seems a bit rubbish though.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
var store = {};

store = {
     dates : dates,
     titles: titles,
     infotxt: infotxt
  };
```

Then access:

`store.dates` or `store.title` or so..

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to store separate related info in arrays as you're doing, and then attempt to access those groups by index.

JavaScript has a perfect, native object that allows you to group similar properties. Just use an object literal:

```
var events = [];

events.push({
  data: someData,
  title: someTitle,
  text: someText
});
```

Now you have what's referred to oftentimes as a "collection".

You could take it a step further and make each event a "class":

```
function MyAwesomeEvent(data, title, text) {
  this.data = data;
  this.title = title;
  this.text = text;
}

events.push(new MyAwesomeEvent(someData, someTitle, someText));
```

That approach is potentially heavy-handed depending on what your specific use-case is, but it's another option.